# Regular expression in PHP with comma

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to extract mark-up from a string. I'm part way there but am having trouble with commas in my pattern.

Take this example input string :

```
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <that index="8"/>consectetur adipiscing elit. <that index="4"/>Sed metus sem, facilisis id nibh eget, <that index="6,2"/>accumsan tristique nisl. Proin iaculis dignissim tincidunt.I said : <that index="9,1"/>
```

I wish to extract the  tags including the attribute 'index'.

I need both variations, ie patterns without and with commas in the attribute.

If I do this :

```
$haystack = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <that index="8"/>consectetur adipiscing elit. <that index="4"/>Sed metus sem, facilisis id nibh eget, <that index="6,2"/>accumsan tristique nisl. Proin iaculis dignissim tincidunt.I said : <that index="9,1"/>';
$regex = '<that index="[0-9,]"\/>';
preg_match_all ( '/' . $regex . '/i', $haystack, $thats );
```

The array $thats only contains this :

```
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => <that index="8"/>
        [1] => <that index="4"/>
    )

)
```

So clearly I am doing something wrong with how I use the comma in the pattern, because it omits those with commas.

Could someone please advise. Thank you.

Comment: You don't have a quantifier going with your charclass, which is why it only ever matches one out of the listed characters `0`-`9` or `,`

Comment: You should *never* parse HTML with regex. Use [PHP DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) instead.

Comment: Why never ? I'm not parsing whole pages or anything. This is not even for HTML, it's short strings with maybe one to two patterns inside...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `+` after the character class to match one or more characters in the given list.

```
$regex = '<that index="[0-9,]+"\/>';
preg_match_all ( '/' . $regex . '/i', $haystack, $thats );
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/mY3rB2/1)

Comment: Thought is must be something like that but I'm still learning this stuff. That worked perfectly, many thanks. I will mark this as the answer as soon as it lets me.